# coloring the vertices of the following graph with 3 colors

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

find the number of way that we can coloring the vertices of  the following graph with 3 colors : red,white and green such that no two adjacent vertices are of the same color; this is called a vertex coloring.

[image]

i think we have $3!$ ways for right above triangle and $2 \times 2$ ways for left above triangle so answer is $3! \times 2 \times 2 =24$
.is this true ?

Comment: As you said and as commented by Morgan, among the $2 \times 2$ ways of coloring the left triangles, in one case you can choose the color of the middle vertex, therefore, the number of possible colorings is $30$.

Comment: @VezenBU: That looks like an answer to me, not a comment.

Comment: Can the graph rotate in 3D or 2D ,because we may need to apply Burnsides' lemma in that situations

Answer (score 1):

As you said and as commented by Morgan, among the $2 \times 2$ ways of coloring the left triangles, in one case you can choose the color of the middle vertex, therefore, the number of possible colorings is $30$ instead of $24$.